# How does mysql replication work?

Tags: mysql, replication

From what I've been able to find in the web, mysql stores statements that alter data in the bin log, which is then read by the slave. What remains unclear is what happens to those statements next? Are they replayed as if they happenned on the slave server?

For example, say there is a query with current time in the conditional, like "UPDATE something SET updatedat = NOW()", and due to the replication delay, the query ends at the slave a couple of seconds later. Will the values in the table be different?

Or if there is master-master replication, at time 1000 the following query happens on server 1:

```
UPDATE t SET data = 'old', updatedat = 1000 WHERE updatedat < 1000
```

At time 1001 on server 2 the following query happens:

```
UPDATE t SET data = 'new', updatedat = 1001 WHERE updatedat < 1001
```

Then server 2 fetches the replication log from server 1, the value on the server 2 will be "old"? If so, is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

> For example, say there is a query with current time in the conditional, like "UPDATE something SET updatedat = NOW()", and due to the replication delay, the query ends at the slave a couple of seconds later. Will the values in the table be different?

No. The replication duplicates the row, which means that the time will be the same